# How to play gif format image?

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework

use Phaser version: 3.8.0
how to load gif image and play it.

`tips
Phaser is a fun, free and fast 2D game framework for making HTML5 games for desktop and mobile web browsers, supporting Canvas and WebGL rendering.`

Comment: hey, welcome to SO. please take some time to read the how to ask a good question guide. it will help you get answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Animated GIF files are [not supported in Phaser](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/37630-playing-gifs-in-phaser-3/), as Phaser is based around the canvas element. The GIF-format is more aimed at animating things in an HTML DOM webpage.

In the Phaser library (and other game related libraries) you usually need more control over the animations anyway, so sprites that switch between walking, ducking, shooting etc.

So I think you need to convert the animation to individual frame images, put those frames in a spritesheet, create a sprite variable in Phaser, add an animation with the frames and then `.play()` that animation.